# How do I force a Chainlink price oracle to return a diffrent price for an asset with Hardhat mainnet forking?

Tags: testing, chainlink, hardhat

I'm working on a DeFi protocol and I would like to test liquidations with Hardhat mainnet forking.

Plan is quite simple:

- Send enough ETH from my test account to the Binance wallet to pay for gas.
- Impersonate the Binance wallet that has a ton of the specified collateral token.
- Send the collateral token to my test account.
- Stop impersonating the Binance wallet.
- Open a vault on my protocol.
- Deposit that collateral token.
- Borrow as much from the vault as possible.
- Mess with the price feed (Chainlink) to bring the collateral price down and cause the vault to be liquidated.

The last step is where I'm stuch at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The [Chainlink Hardhat starter kit](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit) includes [mocks](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit/blob/main/contracts/test/MockV3Aggregator.sol) you may use to simulate a price feed. The initial values of these mocks can be set in the [00_Deploy_Mocks.js](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit/blob/main/deploy/00_Deploy_Mocks.js) file. You can change these to get the price you want initally and then interact with the mock contracts directly to change them further.

To deploy the mocks, if you are using the starter-kit, go to your hardhat project and run

`npx hardhat node`

and then in another terminal (also in the hardhat project directory) run

`npx hardhat deploy`

The starter kit will know you are deploying to a local network and also deploy the mocks.